# Where in my app should I create a SQLite db instance?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm creating an Ionic 2 mobile application that will use a SQLite database to store data. I know I have to use the code bellow to access the database:

```
this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'data.db',
    location: 'default'
})
.then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
        .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    })
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Considering I'll have several pages in my app accessing the db, my question is when should I use the `create` method to get a `db` object instance: Every time I need to execute a command or should I do it once and put the db instance in a global variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a singleton provider which acts as an interface for the sqlite db.

```
@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

 constructor(private sqlite: SQLite){
  this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'data.db',
    location: 'default'
})
.then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
        .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    })
.catch(e => console.log(e));
}


//other db access functions like insert, get, delete etc.
}
```

In your **app.module.ts**, set it as a provider and inject wherever you need.